# Need help using FTP_RENAME in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am working on a website that has some files/folders that are "stored" on the webserver and viewed by the site user.     I need to use some PHP FTP commands to manipulate the folders from an internal control panel.

The FTP is fully accessible and useable via 3rd party FTP software and/or Windows Network Neighborhood as well.    We can add, edit, rename, delete files and folders.

I can get the FTP commands to work, all except for a FTP_RENAME.   This one fails constantly no matter what parameters I pass to it.  I've even tried using getcwd() to see if that mattered, but it didn't.  I've tried full paths, literal paths, etc... in FTP_RENAME.  None work.

The FTP_RENAME commands I use are:

```
$dir = "/web/proofs/";
$old_dirfolderfile=$dir."oldfolder";
$new_dirfolderfile=$dir."newfolder";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($FTP_SERVER);
ftp_login($conn_id, $FTP_UID, $FTP_PWD))
$result=ftp_rename($conn_id, $old_dirfolderfile,$new_dirfolderfile);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

for reference, the code that creates the folder or deletes the folder is:

```
$dir = "/web/proofs/";
$old_dirfolderfile=$dir."oldfolder";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($FTP_SERVER);
ftp_login($conn_id, $FTP_UID, $FTP_PWD);

$result=ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $old_dirfolderfile);
-or-
$result=ftp_delall($conn_id, $old_dirfolderfile);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

These commands work, just the FTP_RENAME fails.

Not sure where to go with this now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When it fails, what error message do you get?

Comment: The return from FTP_RENAME is false... and nothing changes in the folders.   This is the only "error" i see... is the false.

Comment: Make sure you have detailed logging enabled: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: @MartinPrikryl... I "believe" i have them all on...  error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors',1)     still not getting anything displayed.